# remove element from boost::numeric::ublas::vector

Tags: boost, vector, erase

If I declare a boost::numeric::ublas::vector aaa and later call the method aaa.erase_element(n), I get a vector with the same size, but with the n-element equal to zero.
Do you know how can I completely remove the element in order to get a lower-size vector?
I can't use std::vector unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class T> void remove(vector<T> &v, uint idx)
{
    assert(idx < v.size());
    for (uint i = idx; i < v.size() - 1; i++) {
        v[i] = v[i + 1];
    }
    v.resize(v.size() - 1);
}
```

Note: this works if T is a primitive type (int, double, etc.) or simple struct. If T is a pointer
type, or contains pointers, then you may need to look after destruction of referenced objects. Or perhaps use ptr_vector.